# Moving code to production

Tags: apex, app-development, production, developer-edition

I am developing a code in my Dev org. I wish push this change to the production org but I do not have the latest prod copy. How do I go about this? If I copy the prod to Dev first will my new code in Dev will be gone?

Is the process is to move the code from Dev org to UAT and then to prod. Basically I want to know how do I integrate my Dev org code with prod code.do I have to back up my code in github and then move my prod code to Dev, integrate my github code with prod code in Dev? How shall I go about it?

Comment: You can just move the code you want to move to prod via changes. No need to move the whole org.

Comment: But my Dev does not have some of the prod code. I want be careful that the new code doesn't break the existing code. How do I test if the new code integrates well with the old code.

Comment: Proper test methods should be in place to test functionality and ensure that new code or deployments do not affect existing code. thats what they are there for.

Comment: My Dev code does not have prod code. I Believe I should do the test in Dev before I move it production. Now how to I do test in Dev without the production code.

Comment: Please check my edits.

Comment: Once again, if you have proper test methods in your org they will catch any issue during validation. Same thing with the code that is deploying, proper test methods. You missed the first step in not having an up to date sandbox to deploy to. So in addition to the proper test methods, update the dev env with the missing code. Save what you need if you have to refresh and put it back in.  You never said if you had proper test methods in place so I am assuming that you do not so you are left with a need to refresh the sandbox or deploy to another dev env

Comment: Ok thanks. I just have unit test code to test the new functionality that I have built in Dev. I do not have any integration test code.

Comment: if your license includes a fullcopy sandbox, you can create the fullcopy and then apply your dev changes to the sandbox - this will at least let you do some interactive testing to verify that use cases still operate before doing the PROD deployment. Once you get everything deployed, refresh all sandboxes with your prod environment (assuming you don;t have any other dev in-flight)

Comment: What is the SF edition you are using? How many dev SBs are available for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two paths you can take:

1) the simple one is to use ant and any diff tools (most editors can do this). You can download (using ant) the metadata for both orgs. Then use the diff tools to merge and fix any conflicts. The resulting merged directory can be then pushed up (using ant again) to either or both orgs. This is better if this is a one-time problem.

2) the complex one involves leveraging github and one of the "Continuous Integration" tools out there (Jenkins, circle, etc). This is a more involved path but it will definitely help you better if you need to do this a lot over the long term.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing I want to point out is you have not mentioned the use of Sandboxes. I am assuming your UAT environment is either a Developer Pro or Partial Sandbox.

Here is the link to the SDLC guide from Salesforce. It goes into detail on all of your options, from the simplest to the most complex.

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf

Comment: I have a developer pro org and a full Sandbox for UAT